# Compute the following integral: $\int _{\ln3}^{\ln 6}\:8e^xdx$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, definite-integrals

> Compute the following integral:
>
> $$\int _{\ln3}^{\ln 6}\:8e^xdx$$

**My attempt**

We have $$\begin{align}\int \:8e^xdx=8\cdot \int \:e^xdx=8e^x+C\end{align}$$

Now $$\lim _{x\to \ln (3)^+}\left(8e^x\right)=8e^{\ln(3)}=8\cdot3=24$$

and $$\lim _{x\to \ln (6)^-}\left(8e^x\right)=8e^{\ln(6)}=8\cdot6=48$$

Hence $$\int _{\ln3}^{\ln 6}\:8e^xdx=48-24=24$$

How did I do?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The layout of the calculations is hard to look at, on the other hand.

Comment: @TobErnack Much better ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. You also shouldn't use a constant when evaluating a definite integral.

In your case,
\begin{align}
8\int_{\ln 3}^{\ln 6}e^x\,dx&=8\cdot e^x\Bigg|_{\ln 3}^{\ln 6} \\
&=8\cdot (6-3) \\
&=24
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_{\ln 3}^{\ln 6} 8e^x \, dx &= [8e^x]_{\ln 3}^{\ln 6} \\
&=8(\exp(\ln6)-\exp(\ln3)) \\
&=8(6-3)=8(3)=24
\end{align}

I notice that you write equality at every single line such as "$=6$" on one line follow by "$=6 \cdot 8$", it can carry misguiding information.